# Top ten count using Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am using the following mysql query for grouping referrersource.

```
SELECT referrersource,count(referrersource) as counts 
FROM request_events  
where referrersource!='' 
AND landingpage_collectionid=1 
group by referrersource
```

Here, I would like to order by my resultset in ascending order.How can I alter my above query.Any suggections please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT referrersource,count(referrersource) as counts 
 FROM request_events  
 where referrersource!='' 
 AND landingpage_collectionid=1 
 group by referrersource
 ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `ORDER BY counts DESC` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add an [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause.

```
SELECT  referrersource
        ,count(referrersource) as counts 
FROM    request_events 
where   referrersource!='' 
        AND landingpage_collectionid=1 
group by 
        referrersource
order by
        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `ORDER BY` clause, eg.

```
ORDER BY count(referrersource)
```